# Subgroups of a group of order $mp^{\alpha}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I would like to solve the following problem,

Let $G$ be a finite group with order $mp^{\alpha}, (m,p)= 1$. How can I show that for each $|H| = p^n, 1\le n \le \alpha-1$, $H \leqslant G$, there exists $K \leqslant G, |K| = p^{n+1}$ such that $H \unlhd K$?

Now I know how to show this for a $p$-group, but how do I show for a group as above? I also have a doubt that is this even true, as I have a doubt that does all $p$-power groups exist for $G$ or not?

Any Hints?  Thank you.

Comment: the two results I would use: Sylow's theorem (existence) and the fact that if $P$ is a $p$-group and $H<P$ then $H<N_P(H)$ (where $<$ means proper subgroup)

Comment: @RobertChamberlain that is ok, but how to show from these facts, as I need a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{n+1}$.

Comment: I can see this exactly the same as the existence of a subnormal series for a $p$-group. However only I don't have a $p$-group. Maybe you can write a bit more elaborately. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important part of Sylow's theorem is that every $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

So there is some $P\le G$ with $|P|=p^\alpha$ and $H\le P$.

You can prove the result for $P$, so there is some $K\le P\le G$ with $|K|=p^{n+1}$ and $H\trianglelefteq K$.

Comment: So sorry, but I Can't follow the last line!! What to prove for $P$?

Comment: The result (replace $G$ with $P$)

Comment: Ok, so here is my understanding, if $H$ is a subgroup of order $p^i$ for some $1\le i \le \alpha-1$ then its is contained in a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, now for this sylow subgroup (a $p$-group), we get for each subgroup of order $p^j, 1 \le j \le \alpha-1$ another subgroup of order $p^{j+1}$, since all are subgroups of $G$, the statement holds. Is this argument correct?

Comment: For completeness you should also note that $H$ is normal in a subgroup of order $p^{n+1}$, but yes what you've said is correct

Comment: Thsnk You for the answer and clarifications.